# If Button text value is 2 then button should be disable mode

Tags: c#

```
if (Button1 = '2')
{
    Button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

this is my code

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please make sure your question actually contains a question. Interpreting code and figuring out what someone wants without context is rather hard. Please read the [FAQ] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 3):

You should check the `Text` property of the Button and also make sure you are using the equality operator `==`. Using just `=` will try to assign the char value of `'2'` to a control of `Button`, which will not work.

And as per the comments: Compare against a string, not a char.

```
if (Button1.Text == "2")
{
    Button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `== "2"`?

Comment: I guess you are right. Text is string and not char. I'll change it. Thanks

Comment: getting error "Cannot implicitly convert type char to string"

Comment: @santhoshkarthi, notice the double-quotes "2". Do not use single-quotes. Single quotes denote a char, while double notes denote a string.

Comment: if (Button1.Text == "")
        {

            Button1.Enabled = false;
        }

if i provide Button1.Text == "" then its working
but if i provide Button1.Text == "2" its not working

Comment: @santhoshkarthi, you should ensure your Button1.Text is actually "2" and doesn't contain any extra leading or trailing blank spaces.

Comment: Are you sure the text is in the button and not in a TextBox? `if (TextBox1.Text == "2")
{
    Button1.Enabled = false;
}`